# Python/Smtp - envio de múltiplos emails

Tags: python, smtp

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma automação de envio de emails para um departamento de cobrança que consiste em verificar em uma planilha os clientes que não efetuaram pagamento e enviar um email automático aos que não efetuaram. O código em si funciona, porém ele só envia email para uma única pessoa na lista e não todas.
Segue o código abaixo:

```
import openpyxl, smtplib, sys
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#Abre a planilha e obtém o status do último pagamento.

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/temp/cobranca.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

lastCol = sheet.max_column
#latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

#Verifica o status de pagamento de cada cliente.

unpaidMembers = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
  for c in range(3, lastCol + 1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
    if payment != 'ok':
        cliente = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        mes = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
        unpaidMembers[cliente] = email
        print('Linha:',r,'Coluna:',c,'Cliente:',cliente,'Email:',email,'Mês:',mes)

#Faz login na conta de email.

for cliente, email, in unpaidMembers.items():
    body = "cliente: %s | mes: %s" % (cliente, mes)
    #print('sending email to %s...' % (email))
    print(body)

# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()

# setup the parameters of the message
password = "sua_senha"
msg['From'] = "seu_email"
msg['To'] = email
msg['Subject'] = "%s - Honorário em aberto." % (cliente, mes)

# add in the message body
msg.attach(MIMEText(body))

# create server
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')

server.starttls()

# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)

# send the message via the server.
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

server.quit()

print("email enviado com sucesso  %s:" % (msg['To']))
```

Modelo de planilha utilizado: https://prnt.sc/uygcrp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, você precisa apenas ordenar corretamente as instruções dentro do laço:

```
....
# Faz login na conta de email.

# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()

password = "sua_senha"
msg['From'] = "seu_email"

for cliente, email, in unpaidMembers.items():
    body = f"cliente: {cliente} | mes:{mes}" 
    # print('sending email to %s...' % (email))
    print(body)

    # setup the parameters of the message
    msg['To'] = email
    msg['Subject'] = f"{cliente} - Honorário em aberto {mes}."

    # add in the message body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body))

    # create server
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')

    server.starttls()

    # Login Credentials for sending the mail
    server.login(msg['From'], password)

    # send the message via the server.
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

    server.quit()
```

Da forma como estava antes as iterações do laço ocorriam porém como as instruções estavam fora dele os valores de `cliente` e `mes` ficavam apenas para a última iteração, o que também é responsável pela mensagem ser enviada apenas uma vez.
Adicionei **f'string** porque acho mais elegante de trabalhar.

Comment: William Teixeira - Muito obrigado, consegui fazer o envio para mais de um email.